# calling webmethod using jquery

Tags: asp.net

I am having two asp textboxes, *TextBoxPicPostCode* and *TextBoxPicAddress*.

The goal of this task is that when i enter a post code in *TextBoxPicPostCode* and the focus gets lost from this TextBox it should automatically populate *TextBoxPicAddress* using the method in code behind.

The method *getadd()* in .cs code works fine and uses google api but i am not getting an idea how to use jquery ajax with it.

Code-Behind

```
public void getadd()
{
    string address = "";
    //_Address.InnerText = _PostCode.Text;
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + TextBoxPicPostCode.Text + "&sensor=false");
    XmlNodeList distanceX = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("formatted_address");
    if (distanceX.Count > 0)
    {
        address = distanceX[0].InnerXml;
        TextBoxPicAddress.Text = address;
    }
}
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Establishment_Controller.aspx.cs/getadd",
            data: dataValue,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (result) {
                alert("We returned: " + result.d);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Markup

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxPicPostCode" runat="server" 
    CssClass="time" 
    onblur="submit();">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxPicAddress" runat="server" 
    CssClass="address">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make these changes

JavaScript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // change the function name from 'submit' here and at markup
    function FetchAddress() {
        //passing postalCode as string. 
        //Make sure that 'postalCode' is the parameter name at the webmethod
        var dataValue = "{ 'postalCode' : '" + $('.time').val() + "'}";
        //would be worthwhile to read about JSON.stringify, its the standard method
        //var dataValue = JSON.stringify({ postalCode: $(".time").val() });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Establishment_Controller.aspx/getadd", // .cs is not required
            data: dataValue,
            contentType: 'application/json', //charset is not required
            //dataType: 'json', // not required
            success: function (result) {
                var data = result.hasOwnProperty("d") ? result.d : result;
                //alert("We returned: " + result.d);
                // now we are assigning the return value to TextBoxPicAddress
                $(".address").val(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Code-behind

```
//1. webmethod attribute required
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod] 
//2. web methods should be static
//ref: http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/
//3. return type string is needed 
// because we need to fetch the return on the ajax callback
//4. we need to pass TextBoxPicPostCode as a parameter
// because we need to fetch the return on the ajax callback
public static string getadd(string postalCode)
{
    string address = "No Address found!";
    //_Address.InnerText = _PostCode.Text;
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    var remoteXml = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="
        + postalCode + "&sensor=false";
    xDoc.Load(remoteXml);
    XmlNodeList distanceX = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("formatted_address");
    if (distanceX.Count > 0)
    {
        address = distanceX[0].InnerXml;
    }
    return address;
}
```

At markup, change the event as `onblur="FetchAddress();"`

P.S: No time to type all the changes made in detail, so added as comment

Comment: i tested that on my pc. you must be missing something.

Comment: just comment your code and copy paste the webmethod and js and make the change in the html markup `onblur`.

Comment: what is .time and .address here?

Comment: what if i want to call FetchAddress() on clientclick event of aspx button

Comment: @Pranav-BitWiser: if you have a question, please post

Answer (score 0):

`.cs` is Not Required 
and

`public void getadd()`

Should be `Static`
so

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void getadd()
```

JScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                            function submit()
                            {
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "Establishment_Controller.aspx/getadd",
                                    data: dataValue,
                                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                    dataType: 'json',

                                    success: function (result) {
                                        alert("We returned: " + result.d);
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                        </script>
```

EDIT:
You Can't Use Controls Inside Static method. You nee to Refer This:

[Using Jquery Ajax Call](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/jquery-auto-complete-text-box-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/)

[Using AutoCompleteExtender](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201099/AutoComplete-With-DataBase-and-AjaxControlToolkit)

Comment: And what is the difference to javascript code from OP?

Comment: still did not return anything in the textbox

Comment: @HaiderKhattak use FireBug from Mozilla for Debugging

Comment: ok i will but as far as my ajax code is concerned, is it correct...??

Comment: @You need to Declare `public void getadd()` as Static now updated

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar...the controls can now be used when i used static and webmothod with the function

Comment: @HaiderKhattak you cant Use Static Inside Methods.... I included Links in Answer You can refer that

Comment: how can i refer then..??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69116/discussion-between-ganesh-devlekar-and-haider-khattak).

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

**Javascript**
`

```
    function danish() {
        var code = $("#<%=TextBoxPicPostCode.ClientID %>").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "GoogleAPI.aspx/getadd",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: '{code: "' + code + '"}',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                $("#<%=TextBoxPicAddress.ClientID %>").autocomplete({ source: result.d });
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

</script>`
```

**Codebehind**

```
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

[WebMethod]
    public static List<string> getadd(string code)
    {
        string address = "";
        List<string> lst = new List<string>();
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            xDoc.Load(@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + code + "&sensor=false");
            XmlNodeList distanceX = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("formatted_address");
            if (distanceX.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < distanceX.Count; i++)
                {
                    lst.Add(distanceX[i].InnerXml);
                    address = address + distanceX[i].InnerXml;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return lst;
    }
```

Comment: will autocomplete be a good idea onblur of another textbox? i think he is trying to type in a zipcode and fetch the address

Comment: I don't the exact requirement. But by this code he can get list of addresses based on zipcode. He can show in dropdown or any other way as he wants.